# htaccess mod_rewrite with or without query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a vexing problem, where my htaccess, mod_rewrite script is just not hooking up as desired.

Here is my script:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Fix www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,QSA]

# Base rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?localforge.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?$    index.php?sub=localforge&type=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3&p3=$4&p4=$5&p5=$6   [NC,L,QSA]

# Subdomain rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|mail).localforge.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).localforge.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?$    index.php?sub=%1&type=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3&p3=$4&p4=$5&p5=$6   [NC,L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Here is what I’m trying to achieve:

```
#Fix www
```

if there is no subdomain, www is prepended.

---

```
# Base rewrite
```

If the subdomain IS www and regardless of whether or not there is a query string ( up to six parameters ) the rewrite is as follows:

```
index.php?sub=localforge&type=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3&p3=$4&p4=$5&p5=$6
```

---

```
# Subdomain rewrite
```

If the subdomain IS NOT www and regardless of whether or not there is a query string ( up to six parameters ) the rewrite is as follows:

```
index.php?sub=%1&type=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3&p3=$4&p4=$5&p5=$6
```

---

I can handle what happens with the variables passed at process time with PHP.

`# Subdomain rewrite` seems to get hooked only when there is a query string present, returning the subdomain and the query string in the ReWritten variables. If there is no query string `# Base rewrite` seems to be the only hook up.

Any ideas as to what I need to change and/or add to make this work right?

Comment: Can you tell us which redirects or rewrites aren't working for you?

Comment: @anubhava

When a URL with a subdomain other than www is accessed:
If there are parameters in the query string, `sub=%1` returns/passes the subdomain provided.
If there are no parameters in the query string, `sub=%1` returns/passes **localforge** as if the conditions for `# Base rewrite` are being met but not `# Subdomain rewrite` ( as expected ).

Comment: Can you provide me an example of such URL causing this behavior?

Comment: @anubhava
I have a URL to test this.

Comment: I wrote you need to provide an example URL. What is the URL?

Comment: createvtour.com
I have the results of each query processed and echoed by PHP scripting. From this exercise it would seem that in an instance of NO query string, neither of the rewrite rule->conditions are being hooked. This must mean that my RewriteRules only take into account situations with at least one query string element. Which now leads to the question, how do I formulate the RewriteRule so that up to 6 query string parameters OR no parameters will trigger the RewriteRule?

Comment: I finally figured this out. There needed to be two more Rules to handle the www hook:

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?localforge.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule    ^(/)?$    index.php?sub=localforge&type=home   [NC,QSA]`

and...

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|mail).localforge.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).localforge.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule    ^(/)?$    index.php?sub=%1&type=home   [NC,L,QSA]`